# I can't figure out why for-loop doesn't work on this code

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector

I want to make the vector( mycount) that indicates frequency of the elements in myvec. Can you please let me know what is wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num;

    cout << "How many numbers do you want to read in?" << endl;
    cin >> num;


    vector<int> myvec(num);

    std::generate(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), []()->int {return rand(); });

    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
    vector<int> mycount[i] = count(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), myvec[i]);
        cout << mycount[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should at least explain what's wrong.

Comment: Can you tell us what is wrong with this?  Are you getting an error?  garbage values?

Comment: I'm getting errors. like "expression did not evaluate to a constant"

Comment: there may be something wrong in this code. but I can't find it `for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
    vector<int> mycount[i] = count(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), myvec[i]);
        cout << mycount[i] << endl;
    }`

Comment: Something to consider... If you are trying to create a histogram this might give you a weird results. Suppose a value occurs 3 times, myvec[a] = mybec[b] = mybec[c]. Your frequency for the same value will show up in your count array 3 times. mycount[a] = mycount[b] = mycount[c].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you meant to use:

```
vector<int> myvec(num);

// Create a vector for storing the counts as well.
vector<int> mycount(num);

std::generate(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), []()->int {return rand(); });

for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {

   // Get the counts of the element at this index and store it.
   mycount[i] = count(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), myvec[i]);

   cout << mycount[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you , this is what I mean.  but what still can't understand what is wrong with my for loop code?

Comment: @Ezerk, are you asking why `std::vector<int> mycount[i] = ...` is not working?

Comment: Yes, that is my question.

Comment: @Ezerk, That is not a legal syntax to declare/define a variable.

Answer (score 0):

your mycount definition is wrong. Check the below code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num;

    cout << "How many numbers do you want to read in?" << endl;
    cin >> num;


    vector<int> myvec(num);

    std::generate(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), []()->int {return rand(); });

    vector<int> mycount(num); \\declare mycount with num elements

    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
     \\populate the counter for each element
     mycount[i] = count(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), myvec[i]);
        cout << mycount[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but why mycount definition in my code is wrong?  I want to know the reason why I cannot write vector definition in for-loop like my code.

Comment: The syntax is wrong. But you can move the definition inside. The code will work. But on each loop iteration a vector will be created and destroyed (compiler optimizations may be able to avoid it). In that case it is better to use a simple integer `int tmp_count =  count(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), myvec[i]);`